# Is there a way to incorporate f strings in pandas loc output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, f-string, pandas-loc

I'm trying to set up a script which will generate comments for student reports. To set up a general template, I'm using a marks table which has their percentage scores. I'm having trouble using an f string to insert the name of each individual student, as well as any relevant pronouns or taught subject.

At the moment, I've written this:

```
report = pd.DataFrame({'Preferred Name': ['Jack', 'Jenny', 'Bob'],
                       'Topic': ['English', 'English', 'Maths'],
                       'HomeworkAv': [84.6, 68, 94.1]})
name = report['Preferred Name']
topic = report['Topic']
report.loc[report['HomeworkAv'] >= 80, 'TopicSentence'] = f"{name} has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for {topic} throughout the entire term. "
```

The issue is that, for every insertion of a variable in the f string, it lists out every value within that variable. I can see what the clear issue is but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done using `apply` statement.

Here's how I will do it:

```
import pandas as pd
report = pd.DataFrame({'Preferred Name': ['Jack', 'Jenny', 'Bob'],
                       'Topic': ['English', 'English', 'Maths'],
                       'HomeworkAv': [84.6, 68, 94.1]})

report['TopicSentence'] = report.apply(lambda x: f"{x['Preferred Name']} has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for {x['Topic']} throughout the entire term." if x['HomeworkAv'] >= 80 else None, axis=1)
                                
print (report)
```

Or you can also do this:

```
notes = "{} has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for {} throughout the entire term."
report['TopicSentence'] = report.apply(lambda x: notes.format(x['Preferred Name'],x['Topic']) if x['HomeworkAv'] >= 80 else None, axis=1)
```

The output will be:

```
  Preferred Name  ...                                                                              TopicSentence
0           Jack  ...  Jack has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for English throughout t...
1          Jenny  ...                                                                                       None
2            Bob  ...  Bob has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for Maths throughout the ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `.loc()` method together with f-string to achieve the task, you can do it this way:

```
report.['TopicSentence'] = ''     # initialize the sentence to ''
report.loc[report['HomeworkAv'] >= 80, 'TopicSentence'] = report.loc[report['HomeworkAv'] >= 80].apply(lambda x: f"{x['Preferred Name']} has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for {x['Topic']} throughout the entire term. ", axis=1)


print(report)

  Preferred Name    Topic  HomeworkAv                                                                                           TopicSentence
0           Jack  English        84.6  Jack has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for English throughout the entire term. 
1          Jenny  English        68.0                                                                                                        
2            Bob    Maths        94.1     Bob has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for Maths throughout the entire term.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy` it's **`fast`** :

```
import numpy as np
report['HomeworkAv'] = np.where(report['HomeworkAv'] >= 80 , report['Preferred Name'] +  'has consistently demonstrated an excellent understanding for' + report['Topic'] + 'throughout the entire term', '')
```

**Note** : If you've multiple conditions use `np.select`